# Input to each letter's own individual image HTML

Tags: html, css, image, png

I am making a HTML website that takes an `input` in the id `userInput` and was wondering how to take it apart and insert images for the length of `userInput`

Say for example the `userInput` = `Hello World`
Ideally it would out put the images `h.png` `e.png` `l.png` `l.png` `o.png` `space.png` `w.png` `o.png` `r.png` `l.png` `d.png`

As I do not have the files of each individual letter, I am unable to show how it would ideally look, but hopefully you can help me! Though I know that the font disregards capitals.

Thank you once more!

Comment: Why do you want to output images? Are you wanting to achieve a particular look on a web page, or do you want the page to generate image files which you can save? If you are wanting to achieve a certain look, then please draw a sketch of how you want it to look, and edit your question to include it. However, note that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, so you also need to show what you have done so far to try to achieve your end goal.

Comment: Hi @BrettDonald, the font is in images as the font itself cannot be exported to a font file as my client's font is a concept in 3D and the only work around I suggested is to make each letter an image

Comment: Do you want the text in the input field to look like the special font or is it ok to show the special font only when the user has finished inputting?

Comment: @AHaworth After inputting works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write some Javascript to take your input string, convert it to an array, and iterate through the array, creating an HTML string containing the `<img>` tags.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', evt => {
  document.querySelector('.normal-output').innerHTML = evt.target.value
  const a1 = Array.from(evt.target.value)
  const a2 = []
  a1.forEach(e1 => {
    e2 = (e1 == ' ' ? 'space' : e1)
    a2.push(`<img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-76709587/${e2}.png">`)
  })
  document.querySelector('.image-output').innerHTML = a2.join('')
})
```

```css
body, input {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px;}
.image-output img {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" value="abc">
</p>
<p class="normal-output">abc</p>
<p class="image-output">
  <img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-76709587/a.png">
  <img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-76709587/b.png">
  <img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-76709587/c.png">
</p>
```

Comment: I do not quite follow the 3rd block of code as it seems A/B/C.png is hardcoded... I have also tried the 2 blocks above, it does not work.

Comment: The snippet is working for me. The abc in the HTML is just to start as an example, it gets overwritten when the user has finished inputting. Could you describe what isn’t working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution

HTML

```
  <button onclick="generateImages()">Generate Images</button>
  <div id="imageOutput"></div>
```

JS

```
function generateImages() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  var imageOutput = document.getElementById('imageOutput');
  imageOutput.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
    var character = userInput[i].toUpperCase();
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = character === ' ' ? 'FONT/SPACE.png' : 'FONT/' + character + '.png';
    imageOutput.appendChild(image);
  }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as those that contain a runnable snippet and a verbal explanation of what the code does. You can edit your answer to include these details. Perhaps also explain why the answer from @brettdonald does not work for you as it seems fine to me. Thanks.

Comment: You should include edit your question to include this code there.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with this code, so your problem may be elsewhere. Is your site available on the web ... can you include a link to it?

Comment: @BrettDonald I added it as answer as it is the solution i later found :P

Answer (score -1):

To display each letter as its individual image in HTML, you can use the "img" tag for each letter and set the "src" attribute to the URL of the corresponding image.

In this example, each letter (A, B, C) will be represented by its respective image. Replace the image URLs in the "src" attribute with the actual URLs of the images you want to use for each letter.

Remember to make sure that the image files are accessible via the provided URLs or the relative paths if you're hosting the images locally. Additionally, consider using appropriate alternative text ("alt" attribute) for each image to ensure accessibility and improve SEO.

Comment: If this is ChatGPT generated, I would suggest deleting it.